# Azure app service custom domain doesn't work with ws federation

Tags: ssl, azure, asp.net, adfs

So we're developing a web app that will be authenticated with a single-sign-on using on premises adfs server using ws federation.

Everything is working great. If we use our azure url, everything works fine:

eg. somewebsite.azurewebsites.net.

We force https by using the following in our webconfig file:

```
        <!-- BEGIN rule TAG FOR HTTPS REDIRECT -->
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <!-- END rule TAG FOR HTTPS REDIRECT -->
```

However, when we attept to login from the external domain that we've setup, we're forwarded to an error page from the adfs server:

[image: super meaningful error message]

I'm a bit at a loss as to what could possibly be a fix here. Is it an issue with our azure SSL setup? Do I need to add another rule for my force HTTPS business?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out we just needed to set the wReply attribute in our authentication code. Hope this helps somebody out someday.